# Apache Limiting proxypass based on http method

Tags: apache-2.4

I am very new to apache and I have two services one for read and one for writes and both services support same locations. But this routing does not seem to work. Is there anyway I can restrict these based on Http methods

```
 <VirtualHost *:1000>
     ServerAdmin me@example.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost:1000
     ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
     ForensicLog "logs/forensic-log.log"
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
  LogLevel debug
     <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
         
     </Proxy>

     #ReadService only supports GET
     <Location /api/users>
         ProxyPass        http://localhost:5000/api/users connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
         ProxyPassReverse hhttp://localhost:5000/api/calls
     </Location>
     
     #WriteService anything other than GET
 
     <Location /api/users>
         ProxyPass        http://localhost:7000/api/users connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
         ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7000/api/users
     </Location>
     
     
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You may want to try using [mod_allowmethods](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html).

Comment: @tinkertwain thanks for the suggest. but it does not seem to work. Last location match does not allow to pass through other location. In above conf, only POST  gets successful and GET is rejected.

Comment: hmm. How about trying [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#balancer_manager) with [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html). Use %{REQUEST_METHOD} to set a Header and then route using balancer.

Comment: @tinkertwain thanks I will try that out. Though I could achieve the routing I wanted using RewriteCond but not sure how it plays out in load balancer situation. Also there is recommendation to favor ProxyPass instead of RewriteCond when possible, so will resort to using that only when I can't see any options available. :)

Comment: @tinkertwain can you let me know how to route based on header using balancer

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/users(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/api/users(.*)$  http://localhost:5000/api/users$1  [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/users(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/api/users(.*)$  http://localhost:7000/api/users$1  [P]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_URI` is entirely superfluous as you are already checking this in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. No need to wrap the `GET` in parentheses (this unnecessary creates a capturing group - which is not used).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but you can try something like below. You'll need to tweak with the conditional setting of ROUTEID. If the header does not work, you will have to try cookies as outlined in various examples.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET">
        Header set ROUTEID: "1"
    </If>
    <Else>
        Header set ROUTEID: "2"
    </Else>
</IfModule>

ProxyPass        "/api/users" "balancer://mycluster"
ProxyPassReverse "/api/users" "balancer://mycluster"

<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:5000/api/users" route=1
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:7000/api/users" route=2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
```

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for putting this out! Could not edit the answer as it has complaining `edit should be at least 6 chars`.   <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'GET' ">  
But fixing that it did not work. load balancer picks routes in pretty much round robin fashion. So I get success, and method not allowed error consecutively

Comment: Also stickysession seems to only work with cookies or querysrtring and not with header [stickiness details pache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_implementation). Not sure how to add a querystring though

Comment: Let me create an environment similar to yours and test. Stay tuned.